# Get by id last history element

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a huge history table where every table with "actions" come to log

```
IdReg
IdTypeReg
State_prev
Action
State_new
Timestamp
```

And I can't think of a query that says:

- Get a list of `IdRegs`
- where `IdTypeReg` is `@type`
  (*with their last `State_new` by the `Timestamp<@Date`*)
- And which LAST `State_new` NOT IN ('foo','bar')

This means that if the last register on the table history for each ID is in 'foo' or 'bar' this reg won't be shown.

I mean... I've done it before, but I can't seem to recall how.

I can say no cursors are allowed, nor temporal tables, nor too many sub-selects.

@EDIT: Clarification by example

Let's say by **01 January 2013** I have my last **RegId** log **000123** with a **'Ended'**

If I place '02 January 2013' on the param **@date** it **shouldn't display** reg id 000123 whether it was in state 'Working' on Whenevember or not.

It is Ended before @date so I don't want it in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row_number() to do this

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT 
   IdReg,
   IdTypeReg,
   State_prev,
   Action,
   State_new,
   Timestamp,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdReg ORDER BY timestamp desc) rn
FROM 
   actions
WHERE
     Timestamp<@Date 

)
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   Cte
WHERE RN = 1
   and  State_new NOT IN ('foo','bar')
```

Comment: I've seen something like this before... seems it would do the trick... let me try it!

Comment: Nope, if 'foo' is the last by today it still brings it. The timestamp filter won't do what I need it to do.

Comment: hmm I'm having trouble seeing why that would happen perhaps you could share some sample data where this occurs

Comment: that is because the timestamp makes rn = 1 whether if it has ANY reg which hasnt got a 'foo' for that id it will display the last of them And it shouldnt display any of that Id.

Comment: @apacay If I understand your question you just need to apply the state_new filter after the cte instead of before. I removed the ANTI-JOIN option because it became to much of a PIA to construct

Answer (score 0):

I've made this... but I don't like it

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id
        , h1.timestamp
        , h1.old_state   
        , h1.new_state 

FROM    
myTable t 
JOIN history h1 ON (h1.dbid = t.dbid)
JOIN statedef s on t.state = s.id
JOIN (SELECT haux.dbid id, date = MAX(haux.timestamp)
          FROM    cvuser.history haux
          WHERE   haux.timestamp < @date
          GROUP BY haux.dbid
        ) h2 ON (h2.date = h1.timestamp)
where h1.new_state NOT IN ('ThisOne','ThatOne','TheOther')
ORDER BY t.id desc
```

Could anyone improve this a bit?

Comment: I don't like it either.  Why join statedef if it is not used.  You really mean to join h2 on date only.  And column names don't match the question.

Comment: Sorry I've deleted some info... in the Select Distinct I have s.name.. and if I join on date only it brings just the last reg (1 reg), not a list of the regs I need.